# Not loading data from titan graph with cassandra backend using gremlin.

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop-blueprint

I have added data in titan(cassandra backend) using blueprint api with java. I used following configuration in java for inserting data.

```
 TitanGraph getTitanGraph()
{
    conf2 = new BaseConfiguration();
    conf2.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra");
    conf2.setProperty("storage.directory","/some/directory");
    conf2.setProperty("storage.read-only", "false");
    conf2.setProperty("attributes.allow-all", true);
    return TitanFactory.open(conf2);
}
```

Now I am trying to query that database using gremlin. I used following cmd to load it

```
 g = TitanFactory.open("bin/cassandra.local");
```

following is my cassandra.local file

```
 conf = new BaseConfiguration();
 conf.setProperty("storage.backend","cassandra");
 conf.setProperty("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1");
 conf.setProperty("storage.read-only", "false");
 conf.setProperty("attributes.allow-all", true)
```

but when I am running "g.V", I am getting empty graph. Please help

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you commit the changes to your TitanGraph after making graph mutations in your Java program. If you're using [Titan 0.5.x](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/tx.html), the call is `graph.commit()`. If you're using [Titan 0.9.x](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.9.0-M2/tx.html), the call is `graph.tx().commit()`.

Note that `storage.directory` isn't valid for a Cassandra backend, however the default value for `storage.hostname` is 127.0.0.1 so those should be the same between your Java program and cassandra.local. It might be easier to use a properties file to store your connection properties.

Comment: Thanks. I used the same config file and changed to titan0.5.4 all. Thant solved the problem.